# Selecting books from a shelf

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

A shelf contains 24 books. How many ways can 6 books be selected from these 24 with
the restriction that no two selected books can be adjacent?

So first we want to divide by 2 to fulfill the adjacent requirement this give us 12 then we use the bars and star method to get (17 choose 6), is this correct?

Comment: The division by $2$ doesn't look correct to me. This would count that all books are at even position, which is more restrictive than no two books being adjacent.

Comment: then how does one fulfill the adjacent requirement, i think that's what's throwing me off more then anything else

Answer (score 4):

Suppose that we have $18$ books on a long shelf, and acquire $6$ new ones. In how many ways can we **place** these new books, so that no two new books are adjacent?

The $18$ books determine $19$ interbook gaps (we are counting the "gaps" at the beginning and end). We must **choose** $6$ gaps from these $19$.

**Remark:** One can *almost* use Stars and Bars, but need to adjust for the two ends. This is not hard to do, but the approach we used above is more direct.

Comment: And from your answer it follows that $$\sum_{i_1=1}^{14}\sum_{i_2=i_1+2}^{16}\sum_{i_3=i_2+2}^{18}\sum_{i_4=i_3+2}^{20}\sum_{i_5=i_4+2}^{22}\sum_{i_6=i_5+2}^{24}1={19\choose6}$$ or more generally that $$\sum_{i_1=1}^{n-2k+2}\sum_{i_2=i_1+2}^{n-2k+4}\cdots\sum_{i_k=i_{k-1}+2}^n1={n-k+1\choose k}$$

Comment: correct, that's using the stars and bars method.. is this the wrong way to go about it?

Comment: +1 This is indeed a very nice answer! I find it amazing that the question "In how many ways can I take out..." is harder two answer than "In how many ways can I put back...".